# Rudin Theorem 3.26 Series of Nonnegative Terms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> 3.26 Theorem If $0\le{x}<1$ then
>   $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}.$$
>   If $x \ge 1 $ the series diverges.

Why does Rudin allow $0 \le x$ instead of $0 < x$? The result is not true for $x=0$ (even if $n$ is indexed at 1 to avoid $0^0$).

Comment: It is true when $x = 0$ given the (very standard) convention that $0^0 = 1$ for power series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is true for $x=0$ if using the not uncommon convention that $0^0=1$.  There is an extensive discussion of this on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero .

Comment: I see, it does not seem that Rudin explicitly identifies this convention in the textbook (or I may have missed it).

Comment: It's very standard for power series (and polynomials and Laurent series, etc.) so that you can interpret the constant term as an $x^0$ term.